# add a decorate function to a class

Tags: python, class, decorator, descriptor

I have a decorated function (simplified version):

```
class Memoize:
    def __init__(self, function):
        self.function = function
        self.memoized = {}
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwds):
        hash = args
        try:
            return self.memoized[hash]
        except KeyError:
            self.memoized[hash] = self.function(*args)
            return self.memoized[hash]


@Memoize
def _DrawPlot(self, options):
    do something...
```

now I want to add this method to a pre-esisting class.

```
ROOT.TChain.DrawPlot = _DrawPlot
```

when I call this method:

```
chain = TChain()
chain.DrawPlot(opts)
```

I got:

```
self.memoized[hash] = self.function(*args)
TypeError: _DrawPlot() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

why doesn't it propagate self?

Comment: Always inherit from `object` instead of nothing so that you are using new-style classes.

Comment: Don't name methods with capitalized first letters if you have any choice in the matter. Use names like `_draw_plot` (recommended by PEP 8) or `_drawPlot`.

Comment: My answer was misleading so it got the chop. Thanks for the feedback Mike!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you have defined your own callable class then tried to use it as a method. When you use a function as an attribute, accessing the function as an attribute calls it its `__get__` method to return something other than the function itself—the bound method. When you have your own class without defining `__get__`, it just returns your instance without implicitly passing `self`.

Descriptors are explained some on http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#descriptors if you are not familiar with them. The `__get__`, `__set__`, and `__delete__` methods change how interacting with your object as an attribute works.

---

You could implement `memoize` as a function and use the built-in `__get__` magic that functions already have

```
import functools

def memoize(f):
    @functools.wraps(f)
    def memoized(*args, _cache={}): 
        # This abuses the normally-unwanted behaviour of mutable default arguments.
        if args not in _cache:
            _cache[args] = f(*args)
        return _cache[args]
    return memoized
```

or by modifying your class along the lines of

```
import functools

class Memoize(object): #inherit object
    def __init__(self, function):
        self.function = function
        self.memoized = {}
    def __call__(self, *args): #don't accept kwargs you don't want.
        # I removed "hash = args" because it shadowed a builtin function and 
        # because it was untrue--it wasn't a hash, it was something you intended for
        # Python to hash for you.
        try:
            return self.memoized[args]
        except KeyError:
            self.memoized[args] = self.function(*args)
            return self.memoized[args]
    def __get__(self, obj, type):
        if obj is None: #We looked up on the class
            return self

        return functools.partial(self, obj)
```

Note that both of these choke if any of the arguments you pass in are mutable (well, unhashable technically). This might be suitable for your case, but you may also want to deal with the case where `args` is unhashable.

Comment: I prefer the second version, because I can control the cache, I can create more than one Memorize object and so diffent cache for different functions.

I'm using something more complicated that `hash = args`, because I need to handle mutable objects. As you said "hash" is not a very good name.

Comment: @wiso, The first code example would have a different cache for every function you memoized. Always be careful trying to handle mutable types in memoization; they aren't hashable for good reason. You have to understand the way the function *being* memoized works to know whether it is buggy for it or not.

Comment: sorry, but your solution don't work: 
@Memoize
    def function(self, x):
        print self
        return x*x
    
    
    class my_class:
        pass
    
    my_class.do = function
    c = my_class()
    print c.do(2)

TypeError: function() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

Comment: @wiso, Sorry, I should have tested this. I remembered how this worked a little wrong and fixed it. Sorry about that. http://codepad.org/jXkD8QHC